# d3 Zoomable Treemap - Dynamic Text Width per Parent Width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, treemap

I am using the template of the treemap found [here.](http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022)

As it stands currently, I have modified the code a bit so that I am able to show more information as well as include text wrapping for descriptions that run long. In doing this I replaced the following `ptext` and `tspan` tags with `foreignObject` and `xhtml:div` ones, shown below:

Replaced

```
var t = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "ptext")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")

t.append("tspan")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
t.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.0em")
    .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.value); });
t.call(text);
```

with

```
var t = g.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "foreignobj");

t.append("xhtml:div")
    .html(function (d) {
        if (d.status != null) return "<p>Name: " + d.key + "</p>";
        else return d.key;
    })
    .attr("class", "textdiv");

t.append("xhtml:div")
    .html(function (d) {
        if (d.status != null) return "<p>Status: " + d.status + "</p>";
        else return "";
    })
    .attr("class", "textdiv");

t.append("xhtml:div")
    .html(function (d) {
        if (d.description != null) return "<p>Description: " + d.description + "</p>";
        else return "";
    })
    .attr("class", "textdiv");
```

So now the text is able to be wrapped, however the width of the `foreignObject` is not equal to the width of the parent, so the text area is small and overlaps with other `<rect>` areas if the name/status/description is long enough and the text wraps.

I have tried adding in an attribute for the `foreignObject` that is based on the parents height, however this results in an incorrect width that I am assuming is being pulled from the child nodes early on in the rendering of the treemap.

```
var t = g.append("foreignObject")
                .attr("class", "foreignobj")
                .attr("width", $(this).parent().attr("width"));
```

I have also tried finding the closest `<rect>` tag and pulling the width from that, getting the outerWidth, and a few other attempts to no avail.

I'm wondering how the width of the `foreignObject` can be set equal to the width of the parent so that the text wraps only at the edge of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by changing the following code within the `text()` function at the bottom of the script:

```
function text(text) {
    text.selectAll("foreignobj")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; });
    text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; })
        // Added the following line
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x) - 6; });
}
```